# What is the name convention for interfaces in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

Doesn't seem to be an explicit place with this information:

I have always named interface files as `IMyInterfaceName.extension`and the interface as `IMyInterface`.

Is that the way to go with Angular 2 and Typescript?

Thanks :)

Comment: `IMyInterface` would be nice, in 1st suggestion I don't understood `.extension` part

Comment: @PankajParkar: With this I mean .is the extension of the file, whether it's cs, .php, .py, etc.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Thanks :) I got a question, does Angular 2 uses TypeScript naming conventions?

Comment: I had a brief look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines and IMHO Angular follows that guideline. Not sure if the naming conventions you mentioned are the same or something different - any link? AFAIR they used `_` name prefix for private members for a while but moved away. This was probably for easier translation to Dart where members with a name that starts with `_` are private (no `private` keyword).

Comment: And here's the Angular2 API documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/. As you can see, none of the interfaces are prefixed with `I`.

Comment: lol... the other answer doesn't answer this question, well done...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [NAMING.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/NAMING.md).

> In general Angular2 should follow TypeScript naming conventions. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines

This is what it says about interfaces:

> Interfaces:
>
> Follow the same rules as Classes
> Should not have **I** or **Interface** in the name or any other way of identifying it as an interface.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying man! This will do! Thanks for the Naming.md. It seems that everything that Angular2 will do, will go according to typescript.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped!

Comment: @EricMartinez, I can find for interface and class but any suggestions for components?

Comment: Why they don't like 'I'? Its really weerd...

Comment: Hi, can anyone give an example of a file name for interface how it should be like for component we have app.component.ts and for interface what we should follow?

Comment: @AntonPegov because hungarian notation has been out of fashion for a long time. Similarly, we don't call our classes "C" - "CAnimal", "CDog".

Comment: But then there is no way to distinguish Classes from Interfaces in the code.

Comment: @AntonPegov, In general there is no need to indicate interface. If required, the implementation classes will be suffixed with **Impl** to the interface name. eg: `EmailService`, `EmailServiceImpl`

Comment: The first line of linked guidelines says: `STOP READING IMMEDIATELY` . Those guidelines are for TypeScript contributors, not TS users.

Comment: @Episodex: Have to say, that when this question was answered that post wasn't updated like that! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks for this Eric... just an edit on the link to the NAMING.md... link updated to: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/NAMING.md